# Why is cursor not at top of UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have an iPad app (XCode5, ARC, Storyboards, iOS 7).  This is the problem (placeholder and cursor in middle of UITextField):

[image]

This is the code that creates it:

```
- (IBAction)bSendFeedback:(UIButton *)sender {

//  make the popover
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 450, 500)];
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:(CGFloat)1.0 alpha:(CGFloat)1.0];  //  frame color?
popoverContent.view = popoverView;

//resize the popover view shown in the current view to the view's size
popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(450, 500);

//  add the UITextfield to the popover
UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 450, 500)];
[tf becomeFirstResponder];
tf.delegate = self;
tf.tag = kSendFeedback;
tf.placeholder = @" Enter your comments here";
tf.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xFFFFE0);
tf.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;  //  make return key read "Done"
[popoverView addSubview:tf];

//  if previous popoverController is still visible... dismiss it
if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

//create a popover controller
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)oSendFeedback).frame inView:self.view
                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

}

The image is from running under iOS7; *it works fine when running under iOS 6.*
As you can see, it kind of works  but the cursor/placeholder should be at the top of the UITextField... any ideas why it's not there when running under ios&?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that Apple has changed the default vertical alignment of a UITextField to center (`UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter`) in iOS 7 versus top (`UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop`) in iOS 6 & previous version.

To fix it in all versions, please add this line -

```
tf.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
```

This will put the cursor and placeholder text at the top. Good catch !!

Comment: It amazes me that Apple can do something like this without a whisper... yes, very, very good catch!  And it solved the problem!  Thank you so much... SD